Warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.NavigationBaseIncludeIgnored'
With the transition from .net 5 to .net 8, the following warning began to fly:
An error was generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.NavigationBaseIncludeIgnored': The navigation 'TaskEntity.Document' was ignored from 'Include' in the query since the fix-up will automatically populate it. If any further navigations are specified in 'Include' afterwards then they will be ignored.
To be honest, I don't understand how to rewrite this correctly to the new standard, please tell me.
var document = await _context.Documents
    .Include(t => t.Tasks)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Workplace)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.WorkplaceUsers)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.User)
    .Include(t => t.Tasks)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Document)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.ParentDocument)
    .Include(t => t.Tasks)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Document)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.RouteStepValues)
    .Include(t => t.RouteStepValues)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.RouteStepValueProperties)
    .Include(t => t.RouteStepValues)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Element)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.ElementProperties)
    .Include(t => t.RouteStepValues)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Document)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.DocumentType)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Components)
                    .ThenInclude(t => t.ComponentProperties)
    .Include(t => t.RouteStepValues)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Document)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.DocumentType)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Components)
                    .ThenInclude(t => t.ComponentElements)
                        .ThenInclude(t => t.Element)
                            .ThenInclude(t => t.ElementProperties)
    .Include(t => t.RouteStepValues)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Document)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.DocumentAttributes)
    .Include(t => t.RouteStepValues)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Document)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.CardFieldValues)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Element)
                    .ThenInclude(t => t.ElementPropertyDependencies)
                        .ThenInclude(t => t.ElementProperty)
    .Include(t => t.RouteStepValues)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Document)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.ParentDocument)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.CardFieldValues)
                    .ThenInclude(t => t.Element)
                        .ThenInclude(t => t.ElementPropertyDependencies)
                            .ThenInclude(t => t.ElementProperty)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == request.DocumentId);


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes#ignored-navigation

Thanks, I figured out what was wrong.
